# Javascript overlay function with parameters

Tags: javascript

I know overlaying a function without parameters like that : imagine we have a function foo()

```
(function() {
    var origFoo = foo;
    foo = function() {
        alert("something");
        return origFoo.apply(this);
    };
})();
```

But how can I do if the foo prototype was : foo(param1) ?

Comment: `.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)?